# How do I install NetworkManager-wifi on Debian?

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, networkmanager, iwlwifi

I've been fighting my laptop for a few hours now trying to get the wifi to work. I have the drivers installed and `iwlist scan` manages to find the access points in the area, however NetworkManager isn't finding it.

Running `nmcli` shows `wifi (iwlwifi), [REDACTED MAC ADDRESS], plugin missing, hw` and running `rpm -q NetworkManager-wifi` says `package NetworkManager-wifi is not installed`.

Looking about online I found this https://pkgs.org/download/NetworkManager-wifi which lists the package for a number of distros to get the package for but not Debian.

What do?

**EDIT**

`uname -a` outputs

`Linux TheLastMetroid 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` outputs

`03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi`

Comment: mentioning the use of `rpm` on a Debian system... this doesn't make much sense. You should read documentation on the basic usage of Debian. Starting there: https://www.debian.org/doc/

Comment: Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/440628/edit) by adding the output of `uname -a` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: I've edited my post with these additional outputs

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list`? `rfkill` can be installed through `apt install rfkill`.

Comment: With the help of @Chiraang I got it working. In the end we scrapped NetworkManager in favour or wicd which just worked straight away after install.

Answer (score 2):

1. You shouldn't be using `rpm` on Debian (the correct way to check would be `apt-cache show network-manager`
2. If Network Manager isn't installed, you can install it using `sudo apt-get install network-manager`
3. Network Manager is almost certainly installed since `nmcli` seems to be available (which is installed by the `network-manager` package)
4. You almost certainly want to install `network-manager-gnome` instead, since that will give you a nice graphical interface.
5. In Debian, the wifi plugin is provided by the main `network-manager` package as opposed to being in a separate package.
6. The easiest way to install stuff in Debian is through `deb` files (through `apt-get` or `aptitude`), since that is what the repositories run off of. If you want to use `rpm`s by default, you should not be using Debian (check out Fedora or similar, which use `rpm`s by default and use a package manager such as yaourt or yum or whatever).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using rpm was a mistake on my part - still kinda new to this Linux biz. I do already have network-manager and network-manager-gnome (though I couldn't work out how to launch the gnome GUI). Still though it says plugin missing and I can't work out what that might be...

Comment: You might want to uninstall the rpm and re-install the deb package using `apt-get`. I suspect the rpm overwrote some of the binaries or configuration files.

Comment: I got rid of rpm but I'm not sure what you mean by reinstalling the deb package. If you mean NetworkManager I didn't use rpm to install that (or anything for that matter)

Comment: Oh, okay...Can you check that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so` exists?

Comment: Running `cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so` spat out a lot of stuff so yeah, it's there

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Just try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager` - given that the plugin is there, there shouldn't be any issues. It could possibly be a permissions issue or something else, which might be remedied by reinstalling NetworkManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76722/discussion-between-chiraag-and-tupto).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have `wireless-tools` and `wpasupplicant` packages installed.

Comment: I already have both of these